# osticket ldap authentication not happening

Tags: php, php-7.1, osticket

We have migrating the osticket from linux to windows server and in the linux server that osticket is working fine with ldap authentication.

But after migrating into windows server, ldap authentication not happening with the same osticket application.we are getting following error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind() on null in phar://D:/xampp/htdocs/wfmticket/include/plugins/auth-ldap.phar/authentication.php:220

We are using php version 7.1.23 in both linux and windows.

Please help me with this, we are unable to find the cause for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check these things, as I encountered similar issues before:

- Did you install the LDAP PHP extension on the new server?
- Did you properly install and enable the LDAP plugin?
- Is the network connection and LDAP connection to an LDAP server
  working fine?